ReactJS - Porque no me filtra un JSON con un array
estoy intentando hacer que mediante unos checkbox se almacenen en un array los checkbox que estan marcados, hasta aqui bien.
la primera renderizacion se recuperan los datos mediante axios bien pero a la hora de filtrar no filtra:
export const LeftBaseSection = ({ subtypes, setSubtypes }) => {
  const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Actualiza subtypes cuando selectedItems cambia
    const filteredData = subtypes.filter(i => selectedItems.includes(i.code));
    setSubtypes(filteredData);
  }, [selectedItems]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setSelectedItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, event.target.value]);
    } else {
      setSelectedItems(prevItems => prevItems.filter(item => item !== event.target.value));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" value="S3OX" onChange={handleCheckboxChange} /> S3OX
      <input type="checkbox" value="S3sdsdOX" onChange={handleCheckboxChange} /> S3sdsdOX
      {/* Añade más checkboxes según sea necesario */}
    </div>
  );

el json que quiero filtrar es el siguiente, que se recibiria del componente parent en subType junto con su estado setSubtype
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "code": "S34234OX",
        "name": "Pr3e-Pro423ducción",
        "url": "/stwto3x/",
        "types": "USR",
        "description": "Admi3nistrwerwración de Incurridos Diarios SOX",
        "start_date": "2024-04-16",
        "end_date": "2024-04-16",
        "created_at": "2024-04-16",
        "updated_at": "2024-04-16",
        "closed_at": "2024-04-16",
        "created_by": 1,
        "updated_by": 1,
        "closed_by": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "S3OX",
        "name": "Pr3e-Producción",
        "url": "/so3x/",
        "types": "USR",
        "description": "Admi3nistración de Incurridos Diarios SOX",
        "start_date": "2024-04-16",
        "end_date": "2024-04-16",
        "created_at": "2024-04-16",
        "updated_at": "2024-04-16",
        "closed_at": "2024-04-16",
        "created_by": 1,
        "updated_by": 1,
        "closed_by": 1
    }
]


no deberia de ser asi: useEffect(() => {     const filteredData = subtypes.filter(item => selectedItems.includes(item.code));     setSubtypes(filteredData);   }, [selectedItems, subtypes]);

@FranciscoNuñezIALover eso generaria un loop infinito ya que estas seteando la dependencia (el hook se ejecuta si cambia subtypes y en su codigo ejecuta setSubtypes, lo que cambia subtypes). Creo que tiene el problema porque le está pasando subtypes al componente LeftBaseSection desde un componente padre, y el cambio de una prop vuelve a renderizar el componente.

si lo tome en cuenta mira esto haca esta el codigo compleot con los cambios: https://jsfiddle.net/4agcshjt/

Gracias por vuestros comentarios. Lo he conseguido resolver de la siguiente manera:
export const LeftBaseSection = ({ subtypes, setSubtypes }) => {
        const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);
    
        const handleCheckboxClick = (code) => {
            if (selectedItems.includes(code)) {
                setSelectedItems(selectedItems.filter(item => item !== code));
            } else {
                setSelectedItems([...selectedItems, code]);
            }
        };
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const selectedCodes = new Set(selectedItems);
            const filteredSubtypes = subtypes.filter(subtype => selectedCodes.has(subtype.code));
            //setSubtypes(filteredSubtypes);
            console.log(filteredSubtypes)
        }, [selectedItems]);

Por un lado, renderiza tantos checkbox como registros hay (esto solo para la prueba, los checkbox serían fijos, por entidad)
Y con cada click, se actualiza el array selectedItems y posteriormente se genera un nuevo array filteredSubtypes manteniendo el array original subtypes y con cada click se pinta en consola el nuevo array con los objetos filtrados:


Se esta indicando que el valor inicial de selectedItems es un array vacío:
const [selectedItems, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

Por lo tanto se esta vaciando el valor de la prop subtype en el primer render, dentro del efecto:
useEffect(() => {
    // Se tiene la estructura subtypes con valores desde props
    //en el primer render
    //pero selectedItems esta vacio en el primer render
    //el filtro regresa vacio
    const filteredData = subtypes.filter(i => selectedItems.includes(i.code));
    //entonces se hace el set de setSubtypes con filteredData que tiene un arreglo vacio
    setSubtypes(filteredData);
  }, [selectedItems]);

Supongo que en el componente padre se debería de vaciar subtypes despues del primer render, es como si no se enviara ningún valor para subtypes, no hay valor para comparar en el filtro de efecto en el componente LeftBaseSection
Hay que buscar la forma de preservar ese valor de la propiedad subtype despues del primer render, dentro del efecto, por ejemplo si el usuario no ha realizado ningún check:
if(filteredData.length !== 0){
      setSubtypes(filteredData);
} 

Puede que tengas que hacer una re-composición de tus componentes, dependiendo de cual es el objetivo, pero al menos ya sabes cual es el problema.

Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta.
Pues es que ahi es donde estoy echo un completo lio.
Desde BodySection (Parent) llamo al hijo de la siguiente manera pasandole el estado que setea con la llamada de axios
const [subtypes, setSubtypes] = useState([]);

y luego la idea es que
 renderice nuevamente la info al setear setSubtypes desde LeftBaseSection

Veo que ya respondiste a tu propia pregunta y lograste avanzar, que bueno. Ahora, la pregunta fue porque no filtra un JSON y creo que ya te respondimos, si consideras que fue de ayuda considera votar y aceptarla para que el sitio se mantenga bien documentado.
